# What Excel formula returns the sheet name?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

I have searched the excel function documentation and general MSDN search but have been unable to find a way to return the sheet name without VBA.

Is there a way to get the sheet name in an excel formula without needing to resort to VBA?

Answer (score 22):

Not very good with excel,  but I found these [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/return-sheet-name.htm)

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256)
```

and `A1` can be any non-error cell in the sheet.
For the full path and name of the sheet, use

```
=CELL("filename",A1)
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly if any folder in the path of this file contains character ] in its name.

Comment: I thought I was clever by omitting the `,A1`s, and changing `256` to `255`, but that has the bug that it doesn't work if one recalculates the workbook from a different sheet: in that case its value is always the name of the active sheet.

Comment: Very useful, thanks a lot. Just a note, you have to save the file somewhere for this to work (it can't be "Book 1" or whatever).

Comment: @AlexS Thanks for the feedback! It seems the resource I linked originally has changed drastically since I posted this- thank you for confirming it still functions.

Answer (score 8):

## UPDATE 2024: FINALLY A SIMPLE ANSWER

With Excel's introduction of the [textAfter function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textafter-function-c8db2546-5b51-416a-9690-c7e6722e90b4) there is finally a reliable, simple way to acquire the sheet name, thus rendering all once-useful answers, to now be obsolete (including my original answer below).

The formula:

```
=TEXTAFTER(CELL("filename",$A$1),"]",-1)
```

### Notes

- The `-1` parameter ensures that the formula finds the final instance of the `]`, which will *always* be the intended position as a sheet name cannot contain a  `]` character.
- As stated in comments, the optional address parameter within the [Cell Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) *is necessary* for this situation to capture the referenced cell's specific name. Without this, the formula result will be whatever was the activesheet's name when the last recalculation occurred.
- Best to use `$A$1` vs `A1` to avoid an error if copying to upper/left location.
- Despite conflicting documentation, Cell Function [appears to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bNU0.png) a [volatile function](https://exceljet.net/glossary/volatile-function), so the returned result should have minimal interaction with other cells to avoid unnecessary recalculations.
- The workbook will still need to be saved at least once as the [Cell function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) requires a save before it can output the filepath (how could it not?).

  - If somehow this is a concern, you can make your formula more
    idiot-proof by notifying the user of this condition with a formula like this:

```
=IF(CELL("filename")="","~HitSaveForSheetName!~",TEXTAFTER(CELL("filename",$A$1),"]",-1))
```

### Lambda Function

If one wished to convert this to a custom Lambda function, it could be accomplished with the following formula. The optional `cellOnSheet` parameter would empower the user to specify the cell from which to get the worksheet name. Leaving it blank will return the sheet name the formula exists on.

```
=LAMBDA([cellOnSheet],TEXTAFTER(CELL("filename",IF(ISOMITTED(cellOnSheet),!$A$1,cellOnSheet)),"]",-1))
```

[image]

### VBA Solution (For Others)

I'm aware the question clearly states it does NOT want a vba solution. However, others searching this question may not have such a requirement, and the UDF [from this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47927604/11732320) is not a good answer in that it *requires* a cell reference (should be optional) and the result may not display accurate information if sheet name changes before the referenced cell is also changed. The below solution addresses both, with the optional parameter functioning exactly the same as the Lambda function above.

```vb
Function getMySheet(Optional cellOnSheetToGetName As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile
    
    If cellOnSheetToGetName Is Nothing Then
        getMySheet = Application.ThisCell.Worksheet.Name
    Else
        getMySheet = cellOnSheetToGetName.Worksheet.Name
    End If
    
End Function
```

I would recommend the simpler answer above, however, the vba route does have  the following advantages:

- It does not require a save to display
- Has a customized function name to help users
- Works on all instances of Excel

### Older Versions Excel

If you don't have the `textAfter` function, I would contend my solution below is still the most dynamic/robust as it avoids any issues if a folder contains a `]` within it (ie. `C:users\documents\some[old]files\`).

### ORIGINAL POST FROM 2019 (Now Obsolete)

Here's a *reasonably* short one that has a couple benefits:

- Does a reverse lookup (most other answers go wrong direction) by using the often ignored `REPT` function.
- Don't forget to absolute. Copying and pasting some of the other examples could error due to referential changes.
- The `?` is intentional as that shouldn't be in the file path or sheet name.
- Sheet names cannot be longer than 31 characters.

  ```
  =SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("Filename",$A$1), 
  "]",REPT("?", 31)), 31),"?","")
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The below will isolate the sheet name:

```
=RIGHT(CELL("filename"),LEN(CELL("filename"))-FIND("]",CELL("filename")))
```

Comment: This doesn't work if one recalculates the workbook from a different sheet: in that case its value is always the name of the active sheet.

Comment: @feetwet had the same problem, reason is that `CELL("filename")` misses the optional, but in this case necessary reference parameter. Using cell with a reference to any cell in the workbook, "fixes" the behavior as expected: `CELL("filename"; A1)`.

Answer (score 4):

For recent versions of Excel, the formula syntax is:

```
=MID(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("]";CELL("filename";A1))+1;255)
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the formulas given in other answers supports the case if there is character ] in filepath.

The formula below is more complex, but it can handle such cases properly:

```
 =MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1),FIND("?",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"\","?",LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"\","")))))+1,LEN(CELL("filename",A1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a module already open so I made a custom function:

```
Public Function Sheetname (ByRef acell as Range) as string
Sheetname = acell.Parent.Name 
End Function
```

Comment: Looks like your answer is incomplete. Please demonstrate how it answers the original question. Also, use {} button to format as code.

Comment: This is not answering OP's question, as he asked specifically "Is there a way to get the sheet name in an excel formula *without needing to resort to VBA?*", yet this is a VBA answer?

Comment: Not a good answer in that it would display an accurate sheet name if the sheet name were to be changed, while the `acell` remained unchanged. The formula should have `Application.Volatile` within in it to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Had a square bracket ']' in the file name, so needed to modify the above formula as per the following to find the last occurrence of the square bracket.
Verified that this works for 0,1 or more square brackets in the file name / path.

```
=RIGHT(CELL("filename"),LEN(CELL("filename")) - FIND("]]]",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"),"]","]]]",LEN(CELL("filename"))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"),"]","")))))
```

1. Replaces all square brackets using the substitute function, then compares the length of the result with the length of the file name to identify the number of square brackets in the file name.
2. Uses the number of occurrences of square brackets to substitute the last square bracket with 3 sequential square brackets ']]]'
3. Uses the Find function to identify the location of the 3 square brackets in the string
4. Subtracts the location of the 3 square brackets from the length of the full path
5. Uses the result to get the right most characters (being the sheet name)

Previous comment above about saving the workbook first is also a key, as you'll otherwise receive the #Value! result.

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me and is simpler (to me at least) than other solutions, while still handling a square bracket in the file name:

```
=MID(CELL("filename", A1),6+SEARCH(".xlsx]",CELL("filename", A1)),32)
```

This assumes it is an "xlsx" file and that the filename will not contain ".xlsx]" in addition to the xlsx suffix, which in my case is an assumption that is safe enough to make.

If you wanted to handle both ".xlsx" and ".xls" file names, you could use:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename", A1),".xls]",".xlsx]"),6+SEARCH(".xlsx]",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename", A1),".xls]",".xlsx]")),32)
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure you could have Googled this.  I just did, and here is the very first thing that came up for me.

```
In Excel it is possible to use the CELL function/formula and the MID and FIND to return the name of an Excel Worksheet in a Workbook. The formula below shows us how;

=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256)

Where A1 is any non error cell on the Worksheet. If you want the full path of the Excel Workbook, simply use;

=CELL("filename",A1)
```

The only catch is that you have to save the file for this to work!