# How to change sheet name automatically in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In my macro, I will select a cell and insert the Formula. I will insert inside a Table. So it can be automatically draged down. But the problem is My Sheet name "December" will be changed every month. Next month it will be "January" and so on. How to change the formula.

```
=INDEX(Product!$L:$L; MATCH(December!$A3; Product!$I:$I; 0);COLUMNS($A:A))
```

The sheet name will be changed manually. Help me

```
Sub Macro1()
Range("Q3").Value = "=INDEX(Product!C12, MATCH(December!RC1, Product!C9, 0),COLUMNS(C1:C[-16]))"
End Sub
```

Comment: Make an array with the names of the month and reference them from there, or extract them from the current day.

Comment: Why not use ActiveSheet.name to get the worksheet name?

Comment: @mooseman i tried not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all you need is the Month as a `String` of the date, simply use `Format(Date, "mmmm")`

Implemented in your VBA code:

```
Range("Q3").Value = "=INDEX(Product!C12, MATCH(" & Format(Date, "mmmm") & "!RC1, Product!C9, 0),COLUMNS(C1:C[-16]))"
```

Comment: @Deepak you're welcome :) you prefer to use `MonthName(Month(Date))` than `Format(Date, "mmmm")` ?

Comment: @Deepak you can select only 1

Comment: @Deepak select the answer you like most , not to mine because I nagged you

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()        
    Me.Name = Format(Date, "MMMM")        
End Sub
```

Thus the name of the worksheet would be changed every time you click on it, depending on the current month. For the short version of the name, use `Format(Date, "MMM")`.

---

If you want to get the ActiveSheet name from an Excel formula:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))
```

[What Excel formula returns the sheet name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265557/what-excel-formula-returns-the-sheet-name)

Answer (score 2):

Use `MonthName(Month(Date))` in your vba

```
Range("Q3").Value = "=INDEX(Product!C12, MATCH(" & MonthName(Month(Date)) & "!RC1, Product!C9, 0),COLUMNS(C1:C[-16]))"
```

This will currently produce:

```
=INDEX(Product!C12, MATCH(December!RC1, Product!C9, 0),COLUMNS(C1:C[-16]))
```

---

Or you could use `INDIRECT` in your excel formula

```
=INDEX(Product!C12, MATCH(INDIRECT(TEXT(NOW(), "mmmm")& "!RC1",False), Product!C9, 0),COLUMNS(C1:C[-16]))
```

This way it'll update automatically without having to run any vba. However, `INDIRECT` is a volatile function so it can cause slowness in your workbook.

Comment: A very clever solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the name of the current/active sheet using

```
wsname = ActiveSheet.Name
```

Or if the sheet you need is always say the 3rd sheet then

```
wsname = Sheets(3).Name
```

But you can't just replace "December" with this variable, you need to build your formula as a text string. Your test has to be in quotes, while the variable is not.

```
Sub Macro1()
wsname = ActiveSheet.Name
Range("Q3").Value = "=INDEX(Product!C12, MATCH(" & wsname & "!RC1, Product!C9, 0),COLUMNS(C1:C[-16]))"
End Sub
```